# CakePHP $actsAs having no effect except in AppModel?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to implement a Tree of Categories in CakePHP.

If I add this line **in AppModel:**

```
    public $actsAs = array('Tree');
```

and output this from **CategoriesController:**

```
    $behaviors = $this->Category->Behaviors->attached();
    debug($behaviors); die;
```

The result is:

```
    array(
            (int) 0 => 'Tree'
    )
```

But I don't want all my models to behave like Tree. So if I add this in the **Category** model (Category.php):

```
    public $actsAs = array('Tree');
```

And output this from **CategoriesController:**

```
    $behaviors = $this->Category->Behaviors->attached();
    debug($behaviors); die;
```

The result is:

```
    array()
```

Any idea why?
The cookbook here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html#using-behaviors  says that I can use the $actsAs just in the models I need a specific behavior.

Thank you.

Comment: it is not wise to attach a specific behavior like the tree behavior to all models via AppModel. it will only be used for tree-like structured tables and should be applied ONLY in the models that actually are trees. Your code looks fine. Maybe you are calling attached() too early?

Comment: Yep, code definitely looks fine.  You can attach behaviors to one model only, as you have done.  Have you tried using the TreeBehavior to check that it definitely isn't attached?  Is your table definitely set up properly to be using TreeBehavior?

Comment: mark: Sure, I don't like to attach tree behavior via AppModel. How do I know if I am calling attached() too early?

Comment: BadHorsie: The table and everything are just like the example in the cookbook. Yes, I have tried using the TreeBehavior to check & it is definitely not attached. If I use $this->Category->Behaviors->load('Tree'); and then call attached() the TreeBehavior gets attached. But the cookbook says I can use just the $actsAs variable in the model.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I’m changing path dynamically from controller.

CODE :

In Controller ( Where you specifying data to change value of $actsAs variable ) :

```
$custom_path=’/img/cakephp’;
Configure::write(‘path_var’,$custom_path);
```

In Model where you’ll change value in constructor :

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null)
{
  $path = Configure::read(‘path_var’);
  // change actsAs’s different value according to your need
  $this->actsAs['Upload.Upload']['photo']['path'] = $path;
  parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
}
```

- PS : Please write statement Configure::write before model created  :-P
- HAPPY CODING